# IK control bone not rotating linked bone when behind it

Tags: rigging

I have an IK controller bone. It works quite well behind its rest position, moving and rotating both the linked bones. However, when I move the IK controller bone in front of the body, it only rotates the top bone, without modifying the bottom one.

Link to my .blend file is [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29486).

Answer (score 1):

The movements are limited by the IK settings for the lower leg bones. That is the IK settings not the IK Constraint settings. While in pose mode select the lower leg bone and you will find an Inverse Kinematics panel under bone properties.

[image]

There you have enabled a limit and set it to 0-90 degrees for the x-axis. While this does seem like a reasonable setting, it is causing the upper bone to take the rotation when the rotation of the lower leg could be negative.

Comment: Ah, I should have been more clear in my original question. What I need is for the bone to be able to be in the front yet still bend the leg accordingly. Is there a way I can do that? Other rigs of the same character allow it, but I see no differences in the way they are laid out.

Comment: I don't think it's common to enable the limits. To get control over the direction of the bend you place another bone out in front that is set as the pole target for the IK constraint. This also let's you move the knee from side to side while it is bent.